# Pass props from App class to const function React Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo

Im trying to create an React Native App with Expo.
I have a logical error passing props from App class to my Component "Navigator" type const function.
Im not sure how i must to pass the props or how i must to access to them without passing from App:

**App.tsx**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer, StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Navigator from './Components/Navigator';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
   return (
     <NavigationContainer>
       <Navigator props={this.props}/>
     </NavigationContainer>
   );
  }
}
```

**Navigator.tsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import Login from '../Views/Login'
import Home from '../Views/Home'

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function Navigator({props}){
  return (
           <Stack.Navigator>
              <Stack.Screen name="Login" options={{title:'Login.'}}>
                {(props) => <Login {...props} />}
              </Stack.Screen>
              <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{title:'Home.'}}/>
           </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default Navigator;
```

*I have error undefined is not an object (props)*

Comment: Try not destructuring the props: `function Navigator(props) { ` ...

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are make destructuring

Then when you call props it's like doing `props.props`

```
function Navigator(props){// remove {  } from this line
```